Is residual mapping always beneficial?
While reading the residual learning paper [1], I found a problem to be quite unanswered. Suppose I am stacking a deep neural network to map an input to a output. Lets say a function H(x) does the required mapping. The function F(x) represents the residual to be learnt by the layers bypassing the input (x) only to be introduced/added before the output.
Consider a case where my H(x) maps any given instance of variable input x to 0 i.e. H(x) = 0 ∀x∈R. Now for this case F(x) = H(x) - x i.e. F(x) = -x ∀x∈R.
My question is doesn't learning F(x) = -x will be tougher for neural networks as compared to a simple mapping of H(x) = 0? Please explain.

First of all, you can always construct an example to break assumptions.
"Say I take an MLP and generate data according to that MLP, then that MLP is the optimal solution, and anything you add on top of it worsens it, including naive regularization"
Going on your toy problem:

there is a reason if the title says "for Image Recognition"
your counterexample works only for 1D mappings
The problem that the residual network helps with is OPTIMIZATION. In your example, no optimization has been done


Is X universally unilaterally unanimously better?
Probably not. Let's all welcome the "no free lunch theorem".
Is X probably going to help?
We can talk about it
Are residual connections going to help you?
If you have a deep network, most likely

In the paper itself they took an example of 1D mapping to prove their point and hence for I thought of another 1D case. Coming to the optimization part, I didn't ask the question for a particular problem driven approach and I need to get an optimal solution for that problem using a residual connection. I want to understand the residual connection itself not how its used for optimization.

@ishaan "I need to get an optimal solution" with a non-convex loss? good luck
